# Dropdown using Laravel-5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

This is my Controller:

```
 public function create(){

     $categories =DB::select('select Code from ItemCategory');
     return view('item')->with('ItemCategory', $categories);
```

My View file:

```
<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('Link Category') !!}<br />
{!! Form::select('categories', 
    (['0' => 'Select a Category'] + $categories), 
        null, 
        ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
```

But when I run this , I get following error

> InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137:
>     View [item] not found.

PS:
My database table:

```
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID             | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Code           | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| ItemCategotyID | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| ItemLevelID    | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| isActive       | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I have tried [this](http://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/2015/03/30/dynamically-populating-a-laravel-dropdown-box/) example. What is the mistake here? How to get values for a drop down using MySQL table?

Comment: Looks like the controller can't find your view file not a db problem. I'd be checking file names and paths, imports and delving into how the controller finds view files.

Comment: No, I used it properly, all the previous controllers were working well with this view.

Comment: I don't know laravel, but that error message is pretty clear. I wouldn't be relying on assumptions from previous controllers, try replacing the entire db call with an empty array.. dollars to doughnuts you get the same error. Did you step through the code of FileViewFinder.php?

Comment: What is the full name of the view?

Comment: What's the full path of the view file? If it is in a subdirectory under `/resources/views`, then the view need to be called with `"subdir.viewname"`. If this is not the case, then the possible issue is with the namespace.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To load values to drop-down, you have to use **route.php**.

```
Route::get('additem',function(){
  $categories = ItemCategory::all();
  return view('***/***.add_item')->with('categories',$categories);
});
```

You must include your models in **route.php**

```
use App\ItemCategory;
```

Then in your **view** file, use raw html.

```
<div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label('Category', 'Category:') !!}
  <select class="form-control input-sm" name="">
    @foreach($categories as $cats)
      <option value="{{$cats->ID}}">{{$cats->Code}}</option>
    @endforeach  
  </select>
</div>
```

This is how it looks after `dropdown` list gets its values from the database:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

in your create method, do this suppose `ItemCategory` is your model

```
$categories = \ItemCategory::lists('name', 'id');
```

intead of this line

```
$categories =DB::select('select Code from ItemCategory');
```

it will give you this type output

```
array(
 1=>'Cat 1',
 2=>'Cat 2',
 3=>'Cat 3'
.......
)
```

### **Updated**

Laravel deprecated the `lists()` method, and renamed to `pluck`. you can read details in following link, Access link and do scroll little up to the **Deprecations** section.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.1.11

Comment: This just get an empty array [ ], what I need is, I need these values to be in my Dropdown menu of view page.

Comment: Can you share your table structure?

Answer (score 2):

This does not seem to be an issue with what you are retrieving from the DB but rather with your view that you referenced

`return view('item')->...` the view 'item' might not be where you think it is. referenced from laravel docs:

> Of course, views may also be nested within sub-directories of the resources/views directory. "Dot" notation may be used to reference nested views. For example, if your view is stored at resources/views/admin/profile.php, you may reference it like so:

```
return view('admin.profile', $data);
```

On a side note regarding your DB query, you can try to use collections to make your life easier when dealing with views.

Comment: my problem was getting data to a dropdown list. I solved it by using route file. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

In fact you don't need to use "raw html". You can use

```
{!! Form::select('categories', $categories->pluck('Code', 'ID')->all(), null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Comment: View was just a problem, I wanted to get all values from a database table.